How can I fix this horizontal crack in my wooden door?
I installed this door a few years ago. I used some kind of penetrating oil to finish it--unfortunately I can't recall precisely what. The bottom portion now has a split all the way across. The part of the door below the crack is also protruding about a millimetre or two relative to the wood above the crack. In addition, I think I can see some new cracks forming (see second picture).
The crack does not go all the way through the door (there is another panel of wood behind it).
The door is somewhat protected from the elements by a 4-ft overhang, but it still receives some driving rain. It is also located quite close to the ocean.
What can I do to (1) prevent the crack from continuing to widen and spread, (2) pull the protruding wood back and make the face of the door uniform, and (3) prevent the formation of further cracks?




you can fill the crack with wood putty,  but there is no "fixing" it without replacing that part of the door.

I suppose one could also run a decorative inlay across that space. Whether that would be a fix or not depends on how deep the crack goes and how clean you can make the repair. But that's getting toward woodworking rather than home improvement.
